# Spring security Multiple Http Configurations - Ony order(1) works

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Hello I'm trying to build a spring boot app that works both as a web app and a restful api. I'm using spring security and multiple http configurations to secure both purposes but the problem is that only configuration with order(1) annotation works. Separately both configurations work fine but when together only the first one works correctly. I have tried every solution from similar questions but nothing works for me. I would be really glad if someone has any suggestions!

Here are my configurations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class TestSecurity {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class RestWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        public JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        public UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        public JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            return encoder;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
            // user for matching credentials
            // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
            auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    // dont authenticate this particular request
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SUPERVISOR", "PDEMPLOYEE", "EMPLOYEE")
                    // all other requests need to be authenticated
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                    // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                    // store user's state.
                    exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            
            // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
            http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        public DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean
        public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            return encoder;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                    .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from user where username=?")
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from authorities where username=?");

        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic().and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/index").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/index/**")
                    .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER", "SUPERVISOR", "PDEMPLOYEE").anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .logout().permitAll();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like your `RestWebSecurityConfig` wants to define security for `/authenticate` and `/api/**`, so why does it define `anyRequest().authenticated()`? Shouldn't any request to a path other than `/authenticate` and `/api` be handled by the other configuration?

Comment: Did you read this? [Multiple Entry Points in Spring Security | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points)

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thank you so much you saved me!